# Can I constrain a C++ function to accept an arbitrarily nested vector of a specific type?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, c++-concepts

I would like to be able to constrain a C++ function such that the only arguments it can accept are:

```
std::vector<T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>>
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>
...
```

and so on, accepting an arbitrarily nested std::vector, but with a specific type T

I would like the following to compile:

```
template<typename T>
requires IsVectorInt<T>
auto foo(T t)
{

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intvec {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecofvec {{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
    foo(intvec);
    foo(vecofvec);
}
```

So far I have managed to constrain a function using concepts to only accept either:

`std::vector<T>` where T could itself be another std::vector<U>

or:

`std::vector<int>`, this however, does not accept any nested vectors.

My code is shown below:

```
template<class, template<class...> class>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization = false;

template<template<class...> class T, class... Args>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization<T<Args...>, T> = true;

template<class T>
concept IsVector = is_specialization<T, std::vector>;

template<class T>
concept IsVectorInt = IsVector<T> && std::is_same_v<int, typename T::value_type>;

template<typename T>
requires IsVector<T>
auto foo(T t)
{

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intvec {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<std::string> vecofstr {"bar", "baz"};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecofvec {{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
    foo(intvec);
    foo(vecofvec);
    foo(vecofstr); // I would like this line to fail to compile

}
```

Comment: I think that the problem is ill-posed. ```std::vector<whatever>``` is always a nested vector.
Do you have additionnal restriction on T (for instant, only arithmetic types)?

Comment: Yes, T should only be an `int` (or std::string, double, just not another container type). Sorry, I should have clarified that.

Comment: if ```std::string``` can be accepted ```vecofstr``` is valid. If you just want to exclude other container types, you'll have to be more specific as ```std::string``` is a kind of container.

Comment: Are you by any chance using this to make `foo` operate on N-dimensional arrays?

Comment: I'm not actually.. It was mostly as an exercise in using C++20s concepts and requires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify and make your example ***more readable*** by creating a trait to find the inner most type of the vector and then using a `static_assert` as shown below:

```
//trait to get the innermost type 
template <typename T>
struct inner_type
{
    using type = T;
};
//specialization
template <typename T>
struct inner_type<std::vector<T>>
{
    using type = typename inner_type<T>::type;
};
//alias for convenience 
template<typename T>
using inner_type_t = typename inner_type<T>::type;

template<typename T>
auto foo(std::vector<T> t)
{ 
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<inner_type_t<T>>);
}  
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intvec {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecofvec {{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
    foo(intvec);       //works 
    foo(vecofvec);     //works 

    std::vector<std::string> vecofstr{"bar", "baz"};
    //foo(vecofstr);  //fails as expected
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r1sEf7ovn)

---

It is **trivial** to to use `require`(or `enable_if_t`) instead of `static_assert` as shown below:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(std::vector<T> t) requires(std::is_arithmetic_v<inner_type_t<T>>)
{ 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Ksrqnd1f)

Comment: Great answer; I now realise the root of my question was really: How do I get the inner type of my vector?

Comment: @HarryP2023 Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to detect vector or nested vector of arithmetic types, here is a proposal with trait implemented recursively:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct NestedVector : public std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct NestedVector<std::vector<T>>
    : public std::conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value ||
                                    NestedVector<T>::value,
                                std::true_type, std::false_type> {};

// C++<20 version
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<NestedVector<T>::value, bool> = true>
void foo(T t) {}

// C++20 version
// template <typename T>
// requires NestedVector<T>::value
// void foo(T t) {}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> intvec{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<std::string> vecofstr{"bar", "baz"};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecofvec{{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
    foo(intvec);
    foo(vecofvec);
    // foo(vecofstr);  // KO
}
```

(NB: I'm using C++<20 so I removed the requires but I think that it may work juste the same)
[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a8MK157YY)

Comment: Great solution thank you. Would be even better to see a solution using concepts but this works perfectly well.

Comment: @HarryP2023 you can do `template<typename T> concept IsVector = NestedVector<T>::value;` and use it as a concept